# Continuous integration: Where to build the project?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkins server on which I observe a private git repository for changes, which then triggers a pipeline script (the repository contains a nodejs app). In this pipeline script I need to do the following steps:

- Install dependencies (`npm install`)
- Build my application (`npm run build`, which creates a `dist` folder)
- Build a docker container (`docker build`) and run the container (which runs a script in the `dist` folder)

Which of the following two options would be the recommended way to do this, and why?

**Option A:** Run `npm install` and `npm run build` in the jenkins pipeline and copy the `dist` folder to the docker container during the docker build. This would allow me to only install runtime dependencies in the docker container using `npm install --only=production`, therefore reducing the image size significantly.

**Option B:** Run `npm install` and `npm run build` during docker build (In the Dockerfile). This would allow me to run the docker container outside the CI server if I have to (I don't have a use case for it now, but it seems cleaner because it is more independent). However, the image size would significantly increase and I am not sure if this is the recommended way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose option B. 
The reason behind it would be that there are some npm packages that runs a node-gyp, gcc, and other platform-dependent builds. 
Look at the popular bcrypt package as an example.

Going with option A would mean that your docker and Jenkins machine need to hold the same infra for such builds which is not common, to say the least.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. It makes sense to me.